# Yii2 controller extends another controller

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to extend controller from another controller

I have controller "ProjectController" and "MembersController"; is it possible to extend Members controller from Project controller.

so I can get path like:

```
http://localhost:125/yii2/frontend/web/project/members/view?m=12345
```

ProjectController

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

use frontend\models\Project;

/***/
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function actionView($p)
    {
        $model = $this->findProject($id);

        return $this->render('/project/view', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
    }

    protected function findProject($id)
    {
        if (($model = Project::findOne(['project_id' => $id])) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }
}
```

And Members Controller

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\controllers\ProjectController;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

use frontend\models\Members;

/***/
class MembersController extends ProjectController
{
    public function actionView($m)
    {
        $model = $this->findMembers($m);

        return $this->render('/members/view', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
    }

    protected function findMembers($id)
    {
        if (($model = Members::find()->where(['sproject_id' => $id])->all()) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }
}
```

I use `class MemebrsController extends ProjectController` but I get a **404 error page** when I access this url

```
http://localhost:125/yii2/frontend/web/project/members/view?m=123
```

my config file is

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',

    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        /* ****************** */
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<action:(index|login|logout|signup)>' => 'site/<action>',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: You might have to post the configuration of your server as well.

Comment: Also, you need to setup web server `web root` variable correctly. It must be equal to your `web` directory (`.../yii2/frontend/web`)

Comment: what you are asking does not seem to be relevant to what you are trying to achieve. the question is confusing if you want to extend a controller or trying to build url , 2 different things

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I was thinking that url is related to controller

Comment: you can link them like `url -> urlManager -> controller/action`

Comment: Thank you; do you mean in config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OOP it's not good idea to extend `MemberController` form `ProjectController`.

Crate `MemberController` and extend it from `Controller` and then add below rule to your route:

```
'rules' => [
    'project/member' => 'member',
     // ... Other rules
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have extended  project controller using members then you should use

```
http://localhost:125/yii2/frontend/web/members/view?m=123
```

and check for the right  name . you have   MemebrsController  not MembersController

Comment: I want to have : http://localhost:125/yii2/frontend/web/project/members/view?m=123; not only http://localhost:125/yii2/frontend/web/members/view?m=123

Comment: @Bynd To customize URLs you should either use URL manager and URL rules, or create structure using modules. Inheritance of controllers has nothing to do with URLs and it is a bad practice overall.

Comment: @rob006 Ok ; Thank you